# How to use pretrained keras model with batch normalization layer?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a pretrained model with batch_normalization model. When I run:

```
model.layers.get_weights
```

I can see that there are beta/gama values in batch_normalization layers, which means that the model has been trained, and the value has meanings.

I want to load the model and use it in tensorflow. When I run:

```
sess.run(tf.report_uninitialized_variables(tf.global_variables()))
```

It gives me variables from batch_normalization layer:
unitialized_variable

```
array(['pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_11/moving_mean/biased_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_11/moving_mean/local_step_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_11/moving_variance/biased_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_11/moving_variance/local_step_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_15/moving_mean/biased_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_15/moving_mean/local_step_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_15/moving_variance/biased_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_15/moving_variance/local_step_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_9/moving_mean/biased_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_9/moving_mean/local_step_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_9/moving_variance/biased_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_9/moving_variance/local_step_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_13/moving_mean/biased_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_13/moving_mean/local_step_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_13/moving_variance/biased_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_13/moving_variance/local_step_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_16/moving_mean/biased_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_16/moving_mean/local_step_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_16/moving_variance/biased_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_16/moving_variance/local_step_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_14/moving_mean/biased_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_14/moving_mean/local_step_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_14/moving_variance/biased_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_14/moving_variance/local_step_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_10/moving_mean/biased_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_10/moving_mean/local_step_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_10/moving_variance/biased_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_10/moving_variance/local_step_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_12/moving_mean/biased_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_12/moving_mean/local_step_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_12/moving_variance/biased_1',
       'pretrain_variable/pretrain_variable/batch_normalization_12/moving_variance/local_step_1',
       'train_variable/output_y_0/kernel',
       'train_variable/output_y_0/bias',
       'train_variable/output_y_1/kernel',
       'train_variable/output_y_1/bias',
       'train_variable/output_y_2/kernel',
       'train_variable/output_y_2/bias',
       'train_variable/output_y_3/kernel',
       'train_variable/output_y_3/bias',
       'train_variable/output_y_4/kernel',
       'train_variable/output_y_4/bias',
       'train_variable/output_y_5/kernel',
       'train_variable/output_y_5/bias',
       'train_variable/output_y_6/kernel',
       'train_variable/output_y_6/bias',
       'train_variable/output_y_7/kernel',
       'train_variable/output_y_7/bias',
       'train_variable/output_y_8/kernel',
       'train_variable/output_y_8/bias',
       'train_variable/output_y_9/kernel',
       'train_variable/output_y_9/bias',
       'train_variable/output_y_10/kernel',
       'train_variable/output_y_10/bias',
       'train_variable/output_y_11/kernel',
       'train_variable/output_y_11/bias', 'train_variable/beta1_power',
       'train_variable/beta2_power',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_0/kernel/Adam',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_0/kernel/Adam_1',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_0/bias/Adam',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_0/bias/Adam_1',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_1/kernel/Adam',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_1/kernel/Adam_1',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_1/bias/Adam',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_1/bias/Adam_1',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_2/kernel/Adam',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_2/kernel/Adam_1',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_2/bias/Adam',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_2/bias/Adam_1',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_3/kernel/Adam',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_3/kernel/Adam_1',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_3/bias/Adam',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_3/bias/Adam_1',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_4/kernel/Adam',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_4/kernel/Adam_1',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_4/bias/Adam',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_4/bias/Adam_1',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_5/kernel/Adam',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_5/kernel/Adam_1',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_5/bias/Adam',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_5/bias/Adam_1',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_6/kernel/Adam',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_6/kernel/Adam_1',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_6/bias/Adam',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_6/bias/Adam_1',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_7/kernel/Adam',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_7/kernel/Adam_1',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_7/bias/Adam',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_7/bias/Adam_1',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_8/kernel/Adam',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_8/kernel/Adam_1',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_8/bias/Adam',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_8/bias/Adam_1',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_9/kernel/Adam',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_9/kernel/Adam_1',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_9/bias/Adam',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_9/bias/Adam_1',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_10/kernel/Adam',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_10/kernel/Adam_1',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_10/bias/Adam',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_10/bias/Adam_1',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_11/kernel/Adam',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_11/kernel/Adam_1',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_11/bias/Adam',
       'train_variable/train_variable/output_y_11/bias/Adam_1'],
      dtype=object)
```

I have to run this code in order to use the model. I was afraid that this will destroy the parameter in batch_normalization layer. However, I verified that the parameters stayed the same.
So, my question is, why would parameters in batch_normalization layer would be reported as uninitialized, but stayed the same after sess.run(tf.variables_initializer)?

Answer (score 1):

There will be beta, gamma values as these parameters can be initialized, before the model is trained. By default gamma will be initialised to 1 and beta to 0.

Comment: pretrain_model.layers[5].get_weights()[0]
array([0.96893185, 0.95561063, 1.1053786 , 0.93354714, 0.9943648 ,....]
It remained the same after sess.run(tf.variables_initializer([v for v in tf.global_variables() if v.name.split(':')[0] in unitialized_variable])).
The gamma value did not change after tf.variables_initializer.

Comment: @XiangLv That's interesting. Do you mind restating what you are trying to achieve please?

Comment: I am doing something like transfer learning. So, I trained a keras model (conv+batch_normalization+pooling) first and saved it as h5 file. I extracted its middle output.I am doing multi-task learning, and needs to sum the loss of several tasks. So my following layers and optimizers are constructed using tensorflow. Before sess.run(train), I must run(tf.variable_initializer). So, I gathered unitialized variable and found that batch_normalization/moving_mean/moving_variance variable is in it. I think this is very misleading because previously I thought my pretrained model is destroyed.